# Store value from JSON object in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to grab a value in an JSON object, but can't seem to get it. The object is like this,

```
{
"data":{
   "foo":[
      {
         "a":"100",
         "b":"200"
      }
    ],
   "bar":{
      "c":"300",
      "d":"400",
      "e":"500"
    }
 }
}
```

And I need to store what's in bar:d (or 400) in a variable.  How do I get just that value?

I've tried to log to the console:

`$.getJSON('JSONfile.json', function(data) { console.log(data.bar.d); });`

but no success

Comment: What language are you using? JSON is a text-based data format that can be used by many languages.

Comment: did u run your code on the web server ? what's the error? maybe u should run it on the server

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is not valid which causes jquery to quit silently.

Just make sure your response is valid, you can do that in [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: The example I've given is just an example.  I tested the actual data in jsonlint (nice reference, thank you) and it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring the "data" key in the JSON. Try this:

`console.log(data.data.bar.d);`